# Caching data to local disk from web site/browser app

Tags: file, web, unity-game-engine

I am looking into a way to write data to the local disk.   I am working on an application that runs a training tool through websites on the local disk, and need to write data down of what information has been completed.  I know I can't write a file to the local disk because it is a huge security hole, but what I need to do is mark down locally, preferably per user, when they complete a specific training page and look at it later.  As these pages are all read from the local hard drive and opened outside of it.

I am an application (specifically 3D) developer with very limited experience in web development so I am looking for some direction on what to read up on.  This application pre-dates me and I am trying to add more functionality to it.  So if anyone can help point me in the right direction I would appreciate the help.

Also this is all run local and no access to a database to write the information to, so I cannot pursue that route.  I don't care if the data might get wiped out it doesn't need to permanently fixed, eg if the user clears the browsing history it goes away, that is fine.  I would just like it to exist on between restarts.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html%5d). It allows you to store simple data objects locally on a users machine.